# Showing/Hiding appbar causes undesirable movement/animation of main content window

Tags: android, appbar

I'm hiding appbar using

getSupportActionBar().hide();

This works, but the call triggers a smooth animation to hide the appbar and while this animation is running, the Views in the ContentView just below it  move/jump momentarily while they resize themselves to take up the additional screen space available now that the appbar has gone.

In particular, it is important that one of the views in the ContentView remains anchored to the bottom of the screen at all times.

It seems to be something to do with the view hierarchy below the DecorView - (which uses a linear layout)

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks